# Determining type of protocol from hex data

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, soap, protocols

How do I determine that the hex data I receive is a message generated from soap protocol simply by looking at the hex data. For example, if this is what I get:

3c:73:3a:45:6e:76:65:6c:6f:70:65:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:73:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:73:63:68:65:6d:61:73:2e:78:6d:6c:73:6f:61:70:2e:6f:72:67:2f:73:6f:61:70:2f:65:6e:76:65:6c:6f:70:65:2f:22:3e:3c:73:3a:42:6f:64:79:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:78:73:69:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:77:77:77:2e:77:33:2e:6f:72:67:2f:32:30:30:31:2f:58:4d:4c:53:63:68:65:6d:61:2d:69:6e:73:74:61:6e:63:65:22:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:78:73:64:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:77:77:77:2e:77:33:2e:6f:72:67:2f:32:30:30:31:2f:58:4d:4c:53:63:68:65:6d:61:22:3e:3c:53:65:74:4e:61:74:69:6f:6e:61:6c:4c:69:73:74:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:77:77:77:2e:6c:67:65:2e:63:6f:6d:2f:64:64:63:22:3e:3c:6e:61:74:69:6f:6e:61:6c:4c:69:73:74:3e:3c:70:6f:72:74:6e:75:6d:62:65:72:3e:36:30:30:30:3c:2f:70:6f:72:74:6e:75:6d:62:65:72:3e:3c:73:6c:61:76:65:61:64:64:72:65:73:73:3e:37:30:30:30:3c:2f:73:6c:61:76:65:61:64:64:72:65:73:73:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:7a:6f:6e:65:3e:32:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:7a:6f:6e:65:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:69:6e:64:69:76:69:73:75:61:6c:3e:35:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:69:6e:64:69:76:69:73:75:61:6c:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:64:69:6d:6d:69:6e:67:3e:33:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:64:69:6d:6d:69:6e:67:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:70:61:74:74:65:72:6e:3e:36:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:70:61:74:74:65:72:6e:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:67:72:6f:75:70:3e:39:3c:2f:66:6c:61

My application needs to be able to determine that this is a soap message just by looking at the hex data. (As if you convert the above data in ASCII, this is what you get:)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SetNationalList xmlns="http://www.lge.com/ddc">
   <nationalList>
      <portnumber>6000</portnumber>
      <slaveaddress>7000</slaveaddress>
      <flagzone>2</flagzone>
      <flagindivisual>5</flagindivisual>
      <flagdimming>3</flagdimming>
      <flagpattern>6</flagpattern>
      <flaggroup>9</flaggroup>
    </nationalList>
</SetNationalList></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Comment: How about "try to see if you can decode it via ASCII/UTF-8, then try to see if it will parse as xml, then try to see if the root node is an `Element` in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`? (note that the `s` is not important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's just text -> hex, so if you look for

```
78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:73:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:73:63:68:65:6d:61:73:2e:78:6d:6c:73:6f:61:70:2e:6f:72:67:2f:73:6f:61:70:2f:65:6e:76:65:6c:6f:70:65:2f:22
```

you'd match

```
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

Which is the soap definition.